# How can I set the default page for an https request?

Tags: https, security-certificate, iis, iis6, windows-server-2003

We have a website which has a Virtual Directory containing the secure portion of the website.

If users come to `http://www.mydomain.com`, they should get directed to `default.aspx` of the main site, but if they go to `https://www.mydomain.com`, they should go to `default.aspx` of the virtual directory.

The default page for the main site works fine, as does the secure page if I navigate to it using the full name, however I can't figure out how to set the default page for https traffic that doesn't specify a specific page.

1. `http://www.mydomain.com` - Works
2. `https://www.mydomain.com` - Page Not Found
3. `https://www.mydomain.com/myvirtualdirectory` - Page Not Found
4. `https://www.mydomain.com/myvirtualdirectory/default.aspx` - Works

What do I need to do to make links 2 and 3 load the default page show in 4?

My website is running on IIS 6.0 in Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Forsyth - MVP's answer to '[Different file locations for http v https on IIS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122731/different-file-locations-for-http-v-https-on-iis)' suggests that you look at [Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis/) to help identify the fault, I'd also suggest checking the IIS logs to see exactly what is happening to the request for default.aspx, it must be going somewhere!

Comment: Thank you, the issue was with an unrelated website hosted on a different IP address on the same machine which is rewriting URLs that didn't have a default page specified to add `index.php` to it. I would have never found this without the IIS error logs.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to enable https in IIS itself. The following links will help

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=324069

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=298805

Comment: It is enabled.... I want to know how to set the default page for it though because right now I have to manually type in the page name to access it. For example, `https://www.mydomain.com` returns a Page Not Found, however `https://www.mydomain.com/default.aspx` will load correctly

Comment: @Rachel have you looked at [this serverFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/122731/different-file-locations-for-http-v-https-on-iis), the circumstances sound very similar to yours... The second answer has some helpful tips on tracing the source of the error

Comment: @Rachel also see [this answer, again at server fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/148932/https-version-of-page-throws-404-regular-http-appears-fine)

Comment: @toomanyairmiles I am not sure how those links are supposed to help. I have SSL setup correctly, and it works - IF I use the full path name of the page I am trying to reach. I want to know how to make `https://mydomain.com/mysecurevirtualdirectory` display the `Default.aspx` page for the virtual directory instead of a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: @Rachel if you read the answers to both questions they may give you some clues on how to debug this, particularly the answer from Scott Forsyth - MVP as it appears to directly address your situation.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles Thanks, however although Scott's answer addresses the problem, the final resolution is `"I can't guess what would cause this"`. It does provide some debugging steps, but those aren't helping me

Comment: @Rachel I was hoping the debugging steps would help you figure the problem. My only other thought was caught buy LeseMajeste... There is nothing in the logs at all?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles There is something, but I'm not very good at reading IIS logs. It lists 4 files: `default.aspx:80` - status `200`, css style sheet over port 80 - status `304`, `index.php/myvirtualdirectory:443` - `404 0 3`, and `favicon.ico:443` - `404 0 2`. The top default page listed is `default.aspx`, so I'm not sure why it's looking for `index.php`...

Comment: @toomanyairmiles I think I found it, thank you. The issue is with an unrelated website hosted on a different IP address on the same machine which is rewriting the URL to add the `index.php`. If you post that link as an answer, along with a brief description on how to debug IIS errors, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @Rachel answer posted. Glad you got your error fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to redirect could possibly lie in doing a 301 from your option 2 & 3 listed above.

In essence make a default page that the user lands on and set that to automatically redirect to the desired page?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you will need to set up default documents for the secure site, as described in [Setting Up Default Documents](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx) from the IIS 6.0 documentation:

> 1. In IIS Manager, double-click the local computer, right-click the Web Sites folder or an individual Web site folder, and then click
>      Properties.
>
> Note: Configuration settings made at the Web Sites level are inherited
>   by all of the Web sites on the server. You can override inheritance by
>   configuring the individual site or site element.
>
> 1. Click the Documents tab.
> 2. Select the Enable default content page check box.
> 3. Click Add to add a new default document to the list.

Comment: This is already setup on both the main site, and the virtual directory.